# How we can use generator in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**'I want to print List using generator'**

1. can i use generator in map loop
2. I try to use generator but i don't get proper output loop is not break it's continue til end**

- this is the link for codesandbox
  https://codesandbox.io/s/generator-in-react-js-3i1oez?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Perhaps provide insight of what you are trying to achieve? What is broken?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.